# What is the role of express if there is standalone API?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, api, express, architecture

Assuming that I already have a standalone API endpoint(eg: ASP.NET Web API), is there any reason to implement node/express?

eg:
1) Angular <-> Node/express <-> ASP.NET Web API <-> MongoDB
2) Angular <-> ASP.NET Web API <-> MongoDB

Questions: 
1) Any benefits and draw back for implementation 1 and implementation 2?
2) Is it possible for angular to pass query string parameter to node/express and make use of node/express to call asp.net web api instead? If it is possible, is there any advantage of doing this instead of directly accessing the Web API directly from Angular?

Comment: depends where page and resources are served from. Not enough details provided for anyone to evaluate the situation

Comment: @charlietfl page will be served from client side. And resources will be served from the Web API? I am not sure what do you mean by resource in this case. But at the end it will be accessing Web API to get data from DB. So, is there any significance for using angular to call Node/Express to access the api instead of access it directly using $http in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach #1 may be better because of these aspects:

1. It will hide the real API endpoints
2. It is possible to add an extra security layer (e.g. tokens) between the API server and Express server
3. It is not possible to do direct HTTP requests to Web API service if the page was served through HTTPS (a corner case, though good to take in consideration)

Comment: I see. Is there any boilerplate for redirection in node/express? I can't seem to find a tutorial of this. All I seen online is MEAN.

Comment: I can't advise on something specific since it depends on the project itself. Probably the best way to understand your direction is start with Angular <-> Node/express <-> ASP.NET Web API connections.